# Mysql "CREATE VIEW" in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to make this `mysql` syntax in CodeIgniter:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

so that if the view has been successful made, make an additional `CREATE VIEW` from those table generated by previous `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Before asking a question, you might read the documention. What did you try?

Comment: AFAIK there is no method in `CI active record` to create view so you have to go for `$this->db->query(..)` but make sure you clean the vars in the condition. you might read binding and escaping https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html for a secure query if condition vars are not trustworthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

```
$this->db->query('CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE condition');
```

This will work.